# Error during creation of a sidwaystable in LaTeX

Tags: horizontal-alignment

When I create the `sidewaystable` I have a persistent error. The table is always on top where this is an error on table position. I would like to position the table at the page centre. Below is the source code of the head.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[tableposition=below]{caption}
%\setlength{\rotFPbot}{0pt plus 1fil }
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 2fil }
%\robustify\itshape
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
\begin{center}
%\bigskip
%\bigskip
%\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\caption{\label{TableauCapteurs}Comparison of Available Mobility Solutions based on Network Mobility for WSNs and 6LoWPAN}
\label{Tab:Comparison of Available Mobility Solutions based on Network Mobility for WSNs and 6LoWPAN}
\centering\small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
%\captionsetup{type=table}
%\captionabove{very wide table (sidewaystable)}
%\rowcolors{1}{tablebodycolor}{tablerowcolor}
\centering
%\begin{tabularx}{1.25\textwidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}XXXXXXXXXXXX}
%\begin{tabularx}{1.25\textwidth}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}C{1.5cm}|| *{11}{X|}}
\begin{tabularx}{1.25\textwidth}{|C{2.5cm}|| C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|}
\hline
%\rowcolor{tableheadcolor}
%head & head & head & head & head & head \\
%\hline
& \bf test1 & \bf test12 & \bf test3  & \bf test1 &  \bf test1 & \bf test1  & \bf Wang e & \bf test1   & \bf test1  & \bf test1 \\\hline\hline
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) Please provide a full minimal example, this example is not full as there is no `\end{document}`,  (3) Make sure this is minimal by removing stuff that are clearly not related to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your code are several errors.  First of all you have a lot of packages called not neccessary for this problem. Next time please delete all such packages.  Second you called several packages twice.  Please do not do this. If you copy things from templates do only use packages you know and be sure not to call packages twice or more. Third  `\bf` is outdated since years. Use `\textbf{test1}` or `bfseries` instead.

Now your problem:

I added option `showframe` to `geometry` to visualize the typing area.

If you use `sidewaystable` you should remember that then `textwidth` and `texthight` changes their values (of course, because now the higher value has to be the textwidth for the table).  Your used `1.25\textwidth` is too long now. That's the reason your table can not fit the page.  If you use `\textwidth` instead you will get the right value here (See my code and result).
To play with the table I simplified it.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[tableposition=below]{caption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
\centering\small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
\caption{Comparison of Available Mobility Solutions based on Network Mobility for WSNs and 6LoWPAN}
\label{tab:Comparison}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{11}c} % 1.25\textwidth 12cm
\hline
& \textbf{test1} & test2 &  test3  &  test4 & test5 & test6 & Wang e & test8 & test9  & test10 \\\hline\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
      \documentclass{book}
      \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% just for the example
      \usepackage{rotating}
      \usepackage{caption}
      \usepackage{tabularx}
      \usepackage[tableposition=below]{caption}
      \setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 2fil }
      \captionsetup{compatibility=false}
      \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
      \makeatletter
      \makeatother

      \begin{document}
      \begin{sidewaystable*}
      \caption{Comparison of Available Mobility Solutions based on   Network Mobility for WSNs and 6LoWPAN}
      \label{Tab:Comparison of Available Mobility Solutions based on Network Mobility for WSNs and 6LoWPAN}
      \small
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
      \centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C{2.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|}
      \hline
      \bf test1 & \bf test12 & \bf test3  & \bf test1 &  \bf test1 & \bf test1  & \bf Wang e & \bf ab & \bf jk & \bf kl & \bf jh \\
      \hline
      \end{tabularx}
      \end{sidewaystable*}
      \end{document}
```

This is the code. Compile it and see the output. Tick mark the submitted answer, if it's serve your purpose.

Next, time onward post your question with good clarity.

Thanks in advance.